# Ignorar input oculto al hacer tab - jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Como podria hacer que cuando presione la tecla tab, no pase sobre el input que esta dentro de su contenedor que es un **button**. Es decir, al hacer tab, se marca el **button** pero si presiono tab otra vez, se dirige al input oculto (este input tiene ancho y alto de 0px porque necesitaba estilos especificos para hacer el icono de check), y lo que necesito es que lo ignore y se pase a la siguiente tarjeta...

Ademas cuando el focus esta sobre el boton, que al presionar **enter** se seleccione la tarjeta como si fuera un click.
Incluyo el codigo de lo que tengo hasta el momento.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper-card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper-card:hover {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 21px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.wrapper-card:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 21px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  outline: 0;
}

.select-product-area {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

input:checked~.checkmark {
  border-color: blue;
}

input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1.87px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 18px;
}

.checkmark::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 7px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 12px;
  border: solid blue;
  border-width: 0 1.87px 1.97px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="wrapper-card">
    <div class="select-product-area">
      <label class="selected-product" for="tablet-2015">
              <input type="checkbox" id="tablet-2015" name="tablet-2015" data-name-display="tablet-2015" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
    </div>
  </button>

  <button class="wrapper-card">
    <div class="select-product-area">
      <label class="selected-product" for="desktop-2020">
              <input type="checkbox" id="desktop-2020" name="desktop-2020" data-name-display="desktop-2020" />
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
    </div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: porque un input dentro de un button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `tab` se soluciona agregando el atributo `tabindex="-1"` en el `input` que no deseas que se seleccione.

Para simular el click al presionar enter, debes agregar `jQuery`. Además, debes agregar id's en algunos elementos como el botón y el label... *el código de `jQuery` está comentado.*

```js
//Cuando el botón wrapperTablet tenga el focus
$('#wrapperTablet').focusin(function(){
  //Detecta el evento keypress
  $('#wrapperTablet').keypress(function(event){
      //Si la tecla presionada es enter (que equivale al código 13)
      if(event.which == 13) {
        //Simula el evento click
        $('#tablet').trigger('click');
      }
  });
});

$('#wrapperDesktop').focusin(function(){
  $('#wrapperDesktop').keypress(function(event){
      if(event.which == 13) {
        $('#desktop').trigger('click');
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper-card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper-card:hover {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 21px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.wrapper-card:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 21px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  outline: 0;
}

.select-product-area {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

input:checked~.checkmark {
  border-color: blue;
}

input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1.87px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 18px;
}

.checkmark::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 7px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 12px;
  border: solid blue;
  border-width: 0 1.87px 1.97px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="wrapper-card" id="wrapperTablet">
    <div class="select-product-area">
      <label class="selected-product" for="tablet-2015" id="tablet">
         <input type="checkbox" id="tablet-2015" name="tablet-2015" data-name-display="tablet-2015" tabindex="-1" />
         <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </button>

  <button class="wrapper-card" id="wrapperDesktop">
    <div class="select-product-area">
      <label class="selected-product" for="desktop-2020" id="desktop">
        <input type="checkbox" id="desktop-2020" name="desktop-2020" data-name-display="desktop-2020" tabindex="-1"/>
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </button>
</div>
```